# Xamarin error: Connection to the layout renderer failed

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, java-8

Today when I install Xamarin to Visual Studio 2015 it write to me this:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/utils/ILogger
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.utils.ILogger
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=350m; support was removed in 8.0
Exception in thread "main"
```

I don't know why. I have JDK 1.8 and VS2015 How can I fix it?
Thank you for every answer.

Comment: Do you have the Linker enabled and set to `Link All Assemblies`?

Comment: How can I enable it?

Comment: In the project options, disable it completely and retest you app : https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/linking/#Linker_Behavior

Comment: Have you checked this error: [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java)?  Did you have Binding libs to use .jar lib in your project?